# What is the model number, manufacturer, or datasheet of the motor in my picture?

Tags: motor, identification

[image]

It's used for the slush machine of Nostalgia (model: CKSM32CR 120V, 60Hz, 20W). At least I want to know its specifications so that I can simulate my circuit in Falstad.

Comment: Why can't you just simulate it as a simple resistor? 120V, 20W gives you 720R.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you had the datasheet for the motor it's unlikely to specify the inductance and might not specify the power factor. You're going to have to guess.

I'd give a guess at the likely % load and multiply that by the 20 W specification to give power consumption and then apply a power factor of, say, 0.6 and calculate the inductance. Then model the motor with a series RL circuit but bear in mind that only gives you the steady-state equivalent circuit and not the situation during startup.